# SQL replace function with MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: mysql

I would like to use the `replace` function inside a `match` function, to remove `\n` characters before it searches matching rows. Otherwise, for example, if the text  is **FULLTEXT\nsearch**, and the search is **search**, it will not match.

Here is my query (simplified) :

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE MATCH(REPLACE(body,'\\n',' ')) AGAINST ('mysearch' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it throws an error...

#### [EDIT]

After @Shadow 's answer, I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT REPLACE(body,'\\n',' ') AS rb FROM messages) AS rbody WHERE MATCH(rb) AGAINST ('mysearch');
```

I think the idea is correct, but I get an error *ERROR 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to MATCH*. I think this is because I didn't index the column rb (`FULLTEXT INDEX (rb)`), so the `MATCH () AGAINST ()` operation won't work.

So I update my question : **How can one index a column of a subquery**

Comment: Line break is considered a word delimiter, You do not have to remove it for the fulltext search to work.

Comment: In my table it is not stored as a linebreak but as **\n** litterally, because I used the `php` function `mysqli::real_escape_string` before storing it in my database... That's why I need to remove these characters

Comment: fulltext index do not store words less than `ft-min-word-len`/`innodb-ft-min-token-size` (4/3 by default). Space symbols mean nothing in fulltext search except a word delimiter.

Comment: OK but how can I replace **\n** by spaces **before making the fulltext search** ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cannot dynamically remove `\n` character sequence within a `match()` call. As MySQL manual on [match()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) says:

> MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched.

You either have to store `\n` differently, not as a character sequence or you need to have a separate field in which these characters are already filtered out and this additional field is used for fulltext searches.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, waiting for a better solution, I will just add a column `raw_body` to my table, where I will store the exact body (I won't escape it with `real_sacpe_string`, I will just manually replace **"** and **'** by **\"** and **\'**), and I will prepare the query and bind the params. However, I don't know if it is secure enough against sqlinjection.

**[UPDATE]**

Actually I found out that I didn't even needed to manually escape quotes, since the prepared statement is enough to prevent sqli. So I think I will just keep this solution for the moment